# Capture screenshot of all open tabs

Tags: firefox, terminal, webpage-screenshot

Since Firefox 18 a user can take a screenshot of an open tab by pressing `shift+f2` and running `screenshot --fullpage`. Can the Firefox terminal be used to take a screenshot of all currently open tabs?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Best you can do is request a feature